# Google Directory API POSTing new user is suspended because of password

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client, google-directory-api, google-admin-sdk

The application I am developing in JAVA posts user using Google client libraries:
'gsUser = service.users().insert(gsUser).execute()'
The user is created but is suspended by Google within a minute. The reason is :
'Google has suspended an account in your domain due to a potentially leaked password'
The application generates a strong password and SHA-1 encrypted string is set to the gsUser object, still the user is suspended. However the same password set manually is passed for a user if done on Admin console. Any idea? TIA.

Comment: @ale13 any idea!

Comment: Do you have access to G Suite support? If that's the case, I'd suggest you to [contact them](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213).